# Can not connect to azure cosmos db from azure function App using Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-iot-hub, msdn

I am trying to send the incoming data from the IoT in the cosmos DB.
I am receiving data in the function app but sadly I am not able to connect the cosmos DB using the connection string provided( in cosmos DB quickstart and connection string blade.

Below is my node.js application:

```
module.exports = function (context, IoTHubMessage) {
  try {
    var dbName = "temp-db";
    var collectionName = "messages";

    context.log(`JavaScript eventhub trigger function called for message array: ${IoTHubMessage}`);
    context.log(`datatype of message: ${typeof IoTHubMessage}`);
    var json_message = JSON.stringify(IoTHubMessage);
    context.log(`json message: ${json_message}`);

    var mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
    context.log('MongoClient created');
    const pass = "Q********************XTB988aNw4CecjmZsSqTpCeXkjlzCrmljzjq58T9AqeuVvSJrUPBpc4rBSSD1CQ=="    
    const encodedpass = encodeURIComponent(pass)
    const connectionString= `mongodb://iot-db:${pass}@iot-db.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true`

    context.log(`connection string:\n ${connectionString}`)
    mongoClient.connect(connectionString, function (err,client){
    context.log('check0...');
    if(err){
        context.log(`Error occurred while connecting to DB ${err}`)
    } else{
        context.log('MongoClient connected to DB');
    }
      context.log('check1...');

      var collection = client.db(dbName).collection(collectionName);
      context.log('MongoClient collection retreived');
      collection.insertOne(IoTHubMessage, {w: 1});
      //collection.insertOne({"testKey": 13.56}, {w: 1});
      client.close();
      context.log(`Saved message: ${IoTHubMessage}`);
      context.done();
    });

    context.log('check2...');
  } catch (e){
    context.log(`Error ${e}`);
  }

  context.log('Done called');
  context.done();
};
```

Here are the issues that I am facing:

1. The above app does not give any error, but while running the call back function is not getting executed.( i know this because the prints are not happening inside the callback function.)
2. I tried to pass the non-URI encoded password. then it enters the callback function but complains that the password contains illegal characters.
3. on passing the encoded password it does not enter the callback function.
4. How do I check which node driver I am currently using?
5. How do I check if my 10255 port is open or not?

I am attaching a screenshot of the node.js app

[image: screenshot of the code on portal]

Comment: I assume you have to use the Mongo API of Cosmos DB?! If you could use the SQL API instead, you could simply use the binding for Functions and you wouldnt need to deal with any plumbing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#output

Comment: I have mongodb api setup for the database side..

Comment: It looks to me like you are returning too early in your function by calling context.done at the end of your function. That will signal the functions host that the function has returned already even though you'll still have some pending callbacks to be executed. If I recall correctly since the invocation has already finished the context.log calls are ignored. But you should still be seeing the data being inserted. Give that a try, also a further improvement could be to promisify the calls and use async/await which will make your code more readable an easy to follow.

Comment: @nelak so you are saying that i should remove the context.done() API call from inside the call back function.? still on removing the context.done() from the callback function, the call back function is not being executed and data is not being saved in the database.

Comment: The other way around, remove the last context.done and leave the one in the callback so that the callback signals the function execution has finished

Comment: Hi @DurgeshRanjan, has your problem solved by the solution provided by nelak ? If solved, could you please put the solution on the answer area ?